# combining MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a query now that shows me all the calls between this time, is there a way to format it to display "day (9-5)" and "night (5-12)" in one query?

```
select dst, count(dst) as Day from cdr 
WHERE lastapp='Queue' 
AND Date(calldate) = '2012-03-23' 
AND TIME(calldate) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '17:00' 
GROUP BY dst;

+------+-----+
| dst  | Day |
+------+-----+
| 1010 |  10 |
| 1011 |  21 |
| 1012 |   7 |
+------+-----+
```

What I would ideally want is this so I can grab it in an array in PHP without having to do 2 queries.

```
+------+-----+-------+
| dst  | Day | Night |
+------+-----+-------+
| 1010 |  10 |  20   |
| 1011 |  21 |  12   | 
| 1012 |   7 |  4    |
+------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; you can write something like this:

```
SELECT dst,
       COUNT(IF(TIME(calldate) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '17:00', 1, NULL)) AS Day,
       COUNT(IF(TIME(calldate) > '17:00', 1, NULL)) AS Night
  FROM cdr
 WHERE lastapp = 'Queue'
   AND DATE(calldate) = '2012-03-23'
 GROUP
    BY dst
;
```

(`COUNT(...)` counts the number of rows for which `...` was non-null. `IF(boolean, value_if_true, value_if_false)` does what it sounds like — see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if — though I should mention that it's a MySQL-specific function. If you hadn't specifically tagged your question as MySQL, I would have suggested `CASE WHEN boolean THEN value_if_true ELSE value_if_false END` instead, since that's a standard syntax that most or all DMBSes support.)

Comment: Perfect, I was playing with sub-queries that was similar but you filled in the blanks.